# Flash player does not fit size

Tags: html, css, flash

I have a Flash Player and would like to Change the height and width, now I changed the height and the width and get a black Background but the embeded Video does not Change its width and height.

Script:

```
            if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0) {
                alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js.");
            } else {
                AC_FL_RunContent(
                    'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0',
                    'width', '1920',
                    'height', '1080',
                    // 'width', '636',
                    // 'height', '450',
                    'src', 'live',
                    'quality', 'high',
                    'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
                    'align', 'middle',
                    'play', 'true',
                    'loop', 'true',
                    'scale', 'exactFit',
                    'wmode', 'window',
                    'devicefont', 'false',
                    'id', 'live',
                    'bgcolor', '#000000',
                    'name', 'live',
                    'menu', 'true',
                    'allowFullScreen', 'true',
                    'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
                    'movie', 'live',
                    'salign', ''
                    ); //end AC code
            }
```

The generated html

```
<embed width="1920" height="1080" src="live.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" align="middle" play="true" loop="true" scale="exactFit" wmode="window" devicefont="false" bgcolor="#000000" name="live" menu="true" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" salign="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

Comment: Is there a link to see this problem in action?